# Когда я нажимаю на рамку окна с игрой, то приложение замирает, а когда отпускаю - дёргается

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml, box2d

Имеется простенькое приложение на SFML и Box2D
Вот оно, но на код смотреть смысла нет, ибо дело не в нём, но многие "эксперты" считают что я должен его кинуть, ибо они хотят увидеть в простейшем коде какую то ошибку и указать на неё, но тут он не поможет, код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(0.25f / 60.0f);    // 240 FPS
    int windowSizeX = 800, windowSizeY = 600;
    //1.0f / 60.0f - 60 FPS
    //0.5f / 60.0f - 120 FPS
    //0.25f / 60.0f - 240 FPS
    sf::Clock clk;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(windowSizeX, windowSizeY), "Ping-Pong: Lite");
    View view;
    view.setCenter(sf::Vector2f(0.0f, -(windowSizeY / 2)));
    view.setSize(windowSizeX, windowSizeY);
    window.setView(view);
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -1.0f);
    b2World world(gravity);

    {
        b2BodyDef wall;
        b2PolygonShape wallShape;
        //верхняя стенка
        wall.position.Set(0.0f, windowSizeY);
        b2Body* wallBody = world.CreateBody(&wall);
        wallBody = world.CreateBody(&wall);
        wallShape.SetAsBox(windowSizeX, 0.0f, b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f), 0.0);
        wallBody->CreateFixture(&wallShape, 5.0f);
        //нижняя стенка
        wall.position.Set(0.0f, 0.0f);
        wallBody = world.CreateBody(&wall);
        wallShape.SetAsBox(windowSizeX, 0.0f, b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f), 0.0);
        wallBody->CreateFixture(&wallShape, 5.0f);
    }

    RectangleShape rect;
    rect.setOrigin(25.0f / 2.0f, 25.0f / 2.0f);
    rect.setFillColor(Color::White);
    rect.setSize(Vector2f(25.0f, 25.0f));

    //основное тело
    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(25.0f / 2.0f, 25.0f / 2.0f);
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(0, 50);
    b2Body* body;
    body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f; //плотность
    fixtureDef.restitution = 1.0f; //упргугость
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.1f; //трение
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Time dt = clk.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += dt;

        window.clear(Color::Black);
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Button::Left))
        {
            Vector2i pixelPos = Mouse::getPosition(window); //забираем координаты курсора
            Vector2f pos = window.mapPixelToCoords(pixelPos); //переводим их в игровые (уходим от коорд окна)
            pos.y = -pos.y; //убираем минус
            if ((pos.x >= -(windowSizeX / 2) && pos.x <= (windowSizeX / 2)) && ((pos.y >= 0) && (pos.y <= windowSizeY))) //проверяем в окне ли они(по y отрицательное)
            {
                if (body->GetLinearVelocity().x == 0 && body->GetLinearVelocity().y == 0)
                    body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(1, 1));
                b2Vec2 position = body->GetPosition();
                b2Vec2 impulseVector(body->GetPosition().x - pos.x, body->GetPosition().y - pos.y);
                body->ApplyLinearImpulseToCenter(-impulseVector, false);
                cout << pos.x << " " << pos.y << "\n";
            }
        }

        while (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= TimePerFrame;
            world.Step(TimePerFrame.asSeconds(), 6, 2);
        }
        //cout << body->GetPosition().x << " " << body->GetPosition().y << endl;
        rect.setPosition(Vector2f(body->GetPosition().x, -body->GetPosition().y)); //позиция,
            //не забываем привести позицию по y в отрицательное значение
        window.draw(rect);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Так вот, когда я нажимаю на край окна, то приложение замирает(box2d) перестаёт выводить координаты, а когда отпускаю её - то координаты резко изменяются. В чём проблема? Прошу помочь.

Comment: Это классическая проблема, с SDL2 то же самое происходит. Если я правильно помню, с SDL2 кто-то предлагал то ли в event loop'е отлавливать события изменения размера окна и если такое событие пришло, в том же event loop'е выполнять всё рисование, то ли устанавливать колбэк на событие изменения размера, и выполнять рисование в колбэке. Не полностью уверен, что это работает, и что это сработает с SFML.

Comment: Это не "эксперты" считают, это правила сайта. Что тут подразумевается под "краем окна"? Если рамка, то pollEvent не вернется, пока не завершится операция перетаскивания / изменения размера окна.

Answer (score 0):

Этот баг специфичен для Windows и проявляется, если мне память не изменяет, почти во всех подобных библиотеках.
Как вариант попробуй отдельный поток для рендера

Answer (score 0):

Я столкнулся с той же проблемой. Началось с того что решил попробовать SFML, SDL какой-то больно 'сишный', а тут плюсы, ООП. Короче на простейшем OpenGL 2D примере мне очень не понравился ресайз окна за рамку. Перерисовывается только когда отпускаешь кнопку мыши. Решил покопать исходники, форкнул с гитхаба, с пару часов копался. Поскольку в винде, решил добавить WM_SIZING обработку. Не помогло. В обработчики WM_SIZE,WM_SIZING добавил InvalidateRgn/UpdateWindow и вот он косяк самопальной обработки событий вылез наружу. При ресайзе за рамку видно сколько скопилось событий накопленных внутри SFML, когда отпускаю кнопку рисунок догоняет рамку пока не обработает все события. У них своя очередь сообщений!!! Зачем?! Этим всем занимается ОС. Короче решил добавить виртуальных обработчиков и дёргать их при приходе системного события. Результат - всё как и ожидалось, существенное ускорение.
Вот форк, бранч 'noevents'.[NOEVENTS fork](https://github.com/vgui/SFML/tree/noevents)

Comment: Кстати решил создать новый бранч для PR.  Думаю в отдельном неймспейсе типа sf::ne создать такие же классы: Window, WindowBase,WindowImpl,WindowImplWin32. Но в которых не будет использоваться sf::Event. Плюс ещё EventLoop. При этом старый способ с событиями будет работать. Вообще Event лишняя сущность.Куда проще вызывать соответствующий метод с уже установленными параметрами.